# Game Center Leaderboard Per Game

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

Is it possible to have one leaderboard per instance of a game?  I'm looking into how to add score challenges to my iOS game.  My game starts with a random seed, so each individual gets a new game.  I'd like people to be able to share a game with someone else and ask them to try to beat their score.  I'm thinking I'd generate a GKScoreChallenge which would include the seed (although I can't tell if GKScoreChallenge has been deprecated by Apple now), and then use a seed-specific leaderboard to track everyone that that person sent the challenge to.

I understand that you can create leaderboards manually, and according to Apple's last-updated-in-2016 docs you can have a max of 100 leaderboards.  Does this mean 100 leaderboard associated with your app, or 100 "kinds" of leaderboards?  Can I create leaderboards on the fly to support this type of challenge tracking?

Would love the feedback of the community.  And if I'm going down the wrong path here please let me know.  Total n00b when it comes to Game Center.

Thanks